# How to manually set password for MSBuild sign target?

Tags: c#, msbuild, outlook-addin, pfx

We are building an Outlook plugin in C#. It is built without problems in VS and signed with a temporary pfx certificate. We want to put the build process in Jenkins and have it run automatically.

We tried to run the VS solution with MSBuild. It works great on the development machine but in Jenkins there is an error:

> Cannot import the following key file: OutlookPlugin_TemporaryKey.pfx. The key file 
>    may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually 
>    install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: 
>    VS_KEY_A688DC31A30F3EF1

We don't know how to specify the pfx password for the automated build. Or otherwise automate the sign process.

One solution we found was to open the project in VS on the same machine and as the same user as for the automated process and type the password. This doesn't work, probably because Jenkins wipes out the workspace every time. 
If we try to compile without signing and then sign it afterwards, it complains that a ClickOnce assembly must be signed. It seems that Office plugins must use ClickOnce.

So, how to specify the pfx password somewhere in the build file ?

We use VS 2010 with Office Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file (either local or on a well known network share) containing the password as a property and reference that from the MSBuild script. Set permissions on the file such that only the build account can read that file. Note that anyone with admin access to the build machine or that knows the build account password will be able to read the password. Ultimately, there is no silver bullet here. If MSBuild can find/decrypt/whatever the password, a human will be able to, too.

If you are concerned about the security of the private key, consider separating the signing to a separate step and store the private key on a smartcard. It may be overkill but it is one of the best, commonly available protections available.

Otherwise, just add the password as a property. As you know the project files are just MSBuild scripts. For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PfxPassword>password</PfxPassword>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Sample sign task -->
<SignTask>
    <File>MyOutlookPlugin.dll</File>
    <KeyFile>OutlookPlugin_TemporaryKey.pfx</KeyFile>
    <Password>$(PfxPassword)</Password>
</SignTask>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458(v=vs.80).aspx for more information about MSBuild properties.

Comment: The main concern is not the security here. We just don't know how to give the password into the MSBuild script. We use the sln file from the project as a MSBuild script.

Comment: @alexsimi Added information on how to add an MSBuild property.

Comment: We don't have any SignTask in our csproj file. When we run the MSBuild in the console we can see tasks being executed but we cannot tell which one is the sign task so we can override it. Probably because this project is a ClickOnce Outlook plugin and is somehow different from a normal c# project.

Comment: @alexsimi Try configuring the password in Visual Studio then take a copy of the project file. Change the password and do a diff of the file. That will tell you where the password is stored. You may need to check the csproj.user and similar files too.

Comment: @alexsimi .sln file isn't msbuild script.
AFAIK you can create pfx file without password, if this is the option (it could be not due to obvious security issue).
I think you need investigate actual msbuild script that run in your CI and figure what exact task used to sign your exe. Then check it to figure how to specify password for pfx. I suspect it will be done via property, you just need to find exact property name

Comment: After adding <SignTask> to my msbuild file I get an error "The element <SignTask> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized". What do I have to do for this to be recognized? Thanks.

Comment: @Confused I got the same!

Answer (score 1):

We were having issues building the project with MSBuild and Bamboo. The fix for us was to remove the following line from the .csproj file.

```
<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>applicationcert.pfx</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
```

Comment: does removing this actually screw with the build process or setup process?